# autocomplete by jquery in codeigniter textbox id not working

Tags: jquery, html, sql, codeigniter

I am creating form in table and one add button ,one delete button and one submit button.

When I click the add button then one extra row created and when I click delete button the one row goes deleted.

Here is my view page

```
<div style="overflow: scroll;">
<?php
$attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'form');
echo form_open('digital/add_task', $attributes);
?>

<table class="table" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <!--<th>Date</th>-->
            <th>Types of Work</th>
            <th>Worked With</th>
            <th>Director</th>
            <th>No of Hours</th>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>Task Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
            <!-- <td><input type="text" name="date[]" value="" /></td>-->
            <td><input type="text" name="work[]" value="" id="task" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('work[]'); ?></span>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="partner[]" value="" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('partner[]'); ?></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="director[]">
                    <option value="hkn">HKN</option>
                    <option value="anita">Anita</option>
                    <option value="ravi">Ravi</option>
                    <option value="ameesha">Ameesha</option>
                </select>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('director[]'); ?></span>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="time[]" value="" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('time[]'); ?></span>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="task[]" value="" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('task[]'); ?></span>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="status[]" value="" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('status[]'); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<?php
echo form_close();
?>
```

here is my model:

```
public function search_task($qs) {
    /* comparing data with the text box */
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT work_name FROM task_name WHERE work_name LIKE ('$qs%') ORDER BY work_name LIMIT 5");
    /* It checks the row in database table */
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['work_name']));
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set);
    }
}
```

here is my controller:

```
public function task_search() {

    if (!isset($_GET['term'])) {
        exit;
    }

    $qs = strtolower($this->input->get('term'));
    $this->digital_hodm_model->search_task($qs);
}
```

here is my jquery file:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
      case "text":
          newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
          break;
      case "checkbox":
          newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
          break;
      case "select-one":
          newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
          break;

    }
  }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
      if(rowCount <= 2) {
        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
        break;
      }
      table.deleteRow(i);
      rowCount--;
      i--;
    }


  }
  }catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}

</SCRIPT>

<!-- This javascript is used for autocomplete search through database-->

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

        $("#task").autocomplete({
          source: "<?php echo base_url();?>digital/task_search" // path to the task_search method
        });
          });  


</script>
```

My first by default row of table selected autocomplete text from database when I type something in types of work text box but when I am add one extra row by click the add button then in types of work field when I type something then auto complete text is not selected.

Please help me to find the solution

Comment: hey .is any one is available please help me to find the solution it already takes lots of time

Comment: If I get the second types of work input id then it will help me .how i get the input field id.

Comment: In my question i provide the jquery file you can see my jquery file

Comment: hey is there anyone available???

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: one row which is created by html form is selected autocomplete but when i click add button and next row created that row is no selecting the autocomplete

Comment: you are doing for name work field?

Comment: yes..types of work input field

Comment: You are using id here, replace id with class 'task' and then check

Comment: I check it already but it works same as id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117774/discussion-between-deepak-dholiyan-and-aziz).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling autocomplete function on the $("#task"). So the first element with that id gets the autocomplete feature. rest are ignored. So either you add a class to the elements and can call the autocomplete on a class as :

```
$(".someclass").autocomplete({
          source: "<?php echo base_url();?>digital/task_search" // path to the task_search method
        });
          });
```

Or You need to add an id to the new cell generated by jquery. Use this

```
jQuery(this).attr("id","newId");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the "id" attribute to "class" attribute and use following to call an autocomplete: Below are all parameters used

```
    $('.anyClass').autocomplete({
        source:function(keyword, response)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"",
                type:"POST",
                data:keyword,
                dataType:"json",
                beforeSend: function(){
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                },
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
```

Comment: @deepak its not working, even first row is not taking the autocomplete

Comment: hey are you available

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

In my jquery file i called autocomplete in wrong way the right way to auto complete is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){ 
    $(document).on("keydown.autocomplete",".task",function(e){ 
      $(this).autocomplete({ 
      source : '<?php echo base_url();?>digital/task_search' 
      }); 
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed please use the below solution:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){ 
  $(document).on("keydown.autocomplete",".task",function(e){ 
  $(this).autocomplete({ 
  source : '<?php echo base_url();?>digital/task_search' 
  }); 
   }); 
  });
</script>
```

Please remember we need to use jquery .on() function for dynamic elements because dom is loaded already.

Comment: Thanx alot Deepak for helping personally